# What was the reason for Freddy's outburst?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

In *House of Cards, Season 4, Episode 11*, when Freddy mentions to Frank that he'll be leaving his job at the White House, he follows it up with an outburst at Frank's mention of one last plate of ribs for him.

Is this outburst referenced or explained anywhere down the line? Since it hasn't been explained at all until the end of Episode 11, except for the fact that Freddy seems to want to have nothing to do with Frank.

Although from the scene, it does seem so that the outburst was premeditated.

Any idea what was supposed to have brought it on?

Comment: IMO, It's probably due to the fact that because of Frank, Freddy lost almost everything. Sure Frank got him that job but that was due to his own guilt that Freddy got dragged into Franks world as collateral.

As Freddy states, he finally gets something good for himself and Frank doesn't think to congratulate him but instead turns around and asks him to make him some ribs. 

Going off what is actually said later on, Frank explicitly states that he probably cause the row because someone he classes as a friend is leaving him and he doesn't like that.

Comment: @Josh You might want to flesh that out into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The friendship between Freddy and Frank started to strain when Frank didn't stand up for him during season 2, when the media put intense pressure on Freddy *because of Frank*.

Because of this, Freddy lost his business. To a certain extent, Freddy blames Frank for this.

Freddy has been serving ribs for a long time, but it's not something he enjoys. Now that he has actually found a job he enjoys, but Frank still casts Freddy as the 'Ribs guy' - an identity he wants to escape from.

Furthermore, serving food is something a subordinate or servant would do. If Frank truly felt Freddy was a friend, as he claims, then he wouldn't have asked Freddy to *serve* him food before he leaves.

Doing so made Freddy feel like a servant, one that's been toyed around with by Frank, hence he snapped.